# How to allow and validate a specific URL only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you have your Model's `text_field` only be able to accept for example, the Google Maps URL: `http://maps.google.com/` along with anything else typed after `.com/`? Here is an example of what i mean: http://maps.google.com/`maps?complete=0&q=Stanford+University,+Menlo+Park,+CA`.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: `:google_url` is my column in database

```
validate :google_url_only_accepts_gmaps_url

    def google_url_only_accepts_gmaps_url
        errors.full_messages << "This is not GMaps url!" unless
        google_url =~ /^http:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/maps/
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a custom validation for your field:

```
class MyModel
  validate :text_field_only_accepts_gmaps_url
  def text_field_only_accepts_gmaps_url
    errors.full_messages << "This is not GMaps url!" unless
      text_field =~ /^http:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/maps/
  end
end
```

Comment: I did the following but its still allowing anything to be put inside of it. I updated my question to show you what i mean.

Comment: validation only happens when you try to save your object or explicitly check for it's validity using .valid? method - did you do any of these and it still didn't work?

Comment: Isn't my EDIT doing the following? I went onto my form, inserted "asasjasj" and it still saved it, am i missing something?

Comment: you would have to debug it yourself - i just tried it with simple model and validation indeed fails

Comment: Your right, that's strange, its because i put it as an accessible attribute that it didn't work, would you know why?

Comment: no idea.. accessible only makes attributes available for mass assigning. hard to say without looking at code. anyway glad to hear it works now, cheers